# Deploying apex class and visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, deployment

I have an apex class (custom controller) and a VF page. Apex class uses certain standard objects for some manipulation and VF page renders properties found inside controller. Now my question is what are the ways to deploy apex class and VF page to the production? Do I also need to deploy standard object used in controller along with class and page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Force.com IDE then using force.com IDE you can migrate your changes to production. As par my knowledge you dont have to migrate the standard objects. These will automatically be there on production.

Comment: standard objects don't need to be migrated, but custom objects and any custom fields will have to be accounted for, whether by Force.com IDE or change sets.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to deploy to produtction, making the assumption that you're working on a sandbox and new to deployment I'd encourage you to first try making use of change sets.

First you'll have to configure the deployment connection on both your production and sandbox org.

```
Setup> App Setup > Deploy > Deployment connections
```

Once that is done you can make and outbound change set on your sandbox

```
Setup> App Setup > Deploy > Outbound Change Sets
```

Once you've added your Visualforce page and apex class(es) click the add/View dependencies button and you'll see that it will list metadata such as the custom object you're using. Once you upload your change set a target organisation you'll be able to validate and deploy it there. Your customizations only become active when they are succesfully deployed. Keep in mind that removing the change set, will not remove the deployed metadata.